# Representable Functors and Upper Sets (Final Segments)

Tags: category-theory

I was looking around Wikipedia and came across this for representable functors: From another point of view, representable functors for a category $\mathcal{C}$ are the functors *given* with $\mathcal{C}$. Their theory is a vast generalisation of upper sets in posets. I don't get the generalization.

Wikipedia page for representable functors: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representable_functor

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $\mathcal{C}$ be a preorder category. For each object $x$ in $\mathcal{C}$, we have the representable functor $\mathcal{C} (x, -) : \mathcal{C} \to \mathbf{Set}$, which sends an object $y$ to a singleton set if $x \le y$ or an empty set if $x \nleq y$. Thus, we may identify the functor $\mathcal{C} (x, -)$ with the upper set $\{ y : x \le y \}$.

This is part of a bigger story: the functor category $[\mathcal{C}, \mathbf{Set}]$ for a small category $\mathcal{C}$ is analogous to the set $\mathrm{Up} (X)$ of upper sets of $X$ for a preordered set $X$. Just as we have the Yoneda embedding $\mathcal{C}^\mathrm{op} \to [\mathcal{C}, \mathbf{Set}]$, we also have an embedding $X^\mathrm{op} \to \mathrm{Up} (X)$; and just as $[\mathcal{C}, \mathbf{Set}]$ is cocomplete, so too is $\mathrm{Up} (X)$. In fact, $[\mathcal{C}, \mathbf{Set}]$ and $\mathrm{Up} (X)$ are universal in that respect.

Comment: So then how about if we let $\mathcal{C}$ be the category of preordered sets?

Comment: That's not what the statement is about.

Comment: The what happens if we take the category of upper sets?

Comment: We may continue our discussion here: http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/37826/room-for-julian-rachman-and-zhen-lin

Comment: This is a wild guess, but it seems to me that you have some misconceptions about categorification.

Comment: Could you please clear up my misconceptions? Can you explain more as well in your answer?